# implement polynomial multiplication in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm defining some functions for polynomial arithmetic

To make it easier for debugging, I make polynomial list:

```
[5,3,7] -> 5 + 3*x + 7*x^2
```

Here I get function `add` that already works:

```
add [1,9,7] [9,3] == [10,12,7]
```

But I have trouble with `mul`:

```
mul []       _ = [0]
mul (x : xs) ys = add (map (*x) ys) (mul (0 : xs) ys)
```

As I suppose:

```
[4,5,6] * [1,2,3] = 4*[1,2,3] + [0,4,6]*[1,2,3]
```

It takes forever to evaluate `mul [1] [1,2,3]`, I can't find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: In what universe does `(1+9x)+(9+3x) == (10+12x+7x^2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mul []       _  = [0]
mul (x : xs) ys = add (map (*x) ys) (mul (0 : xs) ys)
```

Let's find out what happend when you evaluate `mul [1] [1,2,3]`:

```
mul (1:[]) [1,2,3]
-> add (map (*1) [1,2,3]) (mul (0:[]) [1,2,3])
-> add [1,2,3] (mul [0] [1,2,3])
-> add [1,2,3] (mul (0:[]) [1,2,3])
-> add [1,2,3] (add (map (*0) [1,2,3]) (mul (0:[]) [1,2,3]))
-> add [1,2,3] (add [0,0,0] (mul [0] [1,2,3]))
```

Every time you take out the `head`, another `head`(`0`) is appended to it, thus, Length of your first list (1st argument of `mul`) never change.

So there's no way to reach an exit condition (`first_list == []`).

To fix it, append `0` outside of `mul`:

```
mul []       _  = [0]
mul (x : xs) ys = add (map (*x) ys) (0 : (mul (xs) ys))
```

or perhaps this is more close to your intuition:

```
mul xs ys = if all (==0) xs
                then [0]
                else add (map (*(head xs)) ys) (0 : (mul (tail xs) ys))
```

Comment: Of course `xs == replicate (length xs) 0` should never actually be used. `all (==0) xs` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks, it's much more neat